# CSS: Adding gradiency on hover

Tags: css

Is it possible to add gradiency  on hover? I want to avoid images and use pure css3.

I have a simple box with 
backgroundc-color: blue  whihc has an icon.
I want to add a  gradient effect on mouse over.

How can i get that gradient glow effect as the screen grab?

I am trying to get this effect below:

[image: blue gradient]

Answer (score 2):

You can do gradients in CSS, although the definitions can get a bit verbose. Here's a solid [CSS3 gradient creator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

Then just add a `:hover` to your link.

```
.your-link:hover {
 // gradient here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
.link:hover {
background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 100%, 0, 50% 100%, 116, color-stop(1%, #57fdfe), color-stop(100%, #2c95dd));
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center bottom, farthest-side, #57fdfe 1%, #2c95dd 100%);
background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center bottom, farthest-side, #57fdfe 1%, #2c95dd 100%);
background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(center bottom, farthest-side, #57fdfe 1%, #2c95dd 100%);
background-image: -o-radial-gradient(center bottom, farthest-side, #57fdfe 1%, #2c95dd 100%);
background-image: radial-gradient(farthest-side at center bottom, #57fdfe 1%, #2c95dd 100%);
}
```

Thats a complete example, you can just copy and paste and it should work :) enjoy!

Note that has your colours in there and its radial :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of thing you are looking for?
Obviously use your own colors.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yentup/DrRda/)

This is the css:

```css
.blah:hover {
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0198E1), to(#00FFFF));
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0198E1, #00FFFF); 
   background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0198E1, #00FFFF);
   background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0198E1, #00FFFF);
   background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #0198E1, #00FFFF);
}
```

Comment: @yentup- thankyou. its work on FF but doesnt  work on IE9. Is there away to make it work on IE9?

Comment: I'm not sure. I left out the default one, maybe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yentup/DrRda/1/) works? I dont have IE so i can never test it

Answer (score 0):

For best practices for css3, you can go to css3please.com. Just adding :hover to the class will give you what you need:

```
.box_gradient:hover {
  background-color: #444444;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444444), to(#999999)); /* Chrome, Safari 4+ */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Chrome 10-25, iOS 5+, Safari 5.1+ */
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Firefox 3.6-15 */
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Opera 11.10-12.00 */
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #444444, #999999); /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.50+ */
}
```